# Focus and Highlight An Input Control

Tags: jquery

When the page loads, I want to focus and highlight (border color or background color change) an input control. How can I do it? This is what I got so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txt1").focus();            
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at CSS [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afocus) selector. And just specify CSS class like:

```
#txt1:focus {
    border-color:red;
}
```

As it is not supported by older browsers (IE7 plus some other). You may want to do that with JS.

```
$("#txt1").focus(function(){ $(this).addClass("focused")});
$("#txt1").blur(function(){ $(this).removeClass("focused")});
```

Where `focused` is defined like this:

```
#txt1.focused {
   border-color:red;
}
```

**EDIT:**

[Jquery.focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) docs.

```
$("#txt1").focus(function(){ $(this).addClass("focused")});
```

Line above simply binds a handler to focus event and does not change a focus or execute it immediately. In order to get a field focused on page load another line should be added after that one:

```
$("#txt1").focus();
```

This one will set a focus on selected element and run a handler attached previously.
Shorter notation:

```
$("#txt1").focus(function(){ $(this).addClass("focused")}).focus();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/3/) with element autofucused on page load

Comment: Or do something even more general like `input[type="text"]:focus { border:#ff000; }` for any textbox that's focused

Comment: Your answer looks promising. I will be back in 2 mins

Comment: My fall. Wrongly formatted CSS property. Take a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/2/

Comment: Is it just me? I tried this demo http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/2/ in Chrome and it does not highlight the textbox and no focus either

Comment: I mean when the page loads, it does not set focus on the textbox

Comment: Ok. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/3/ :) Suppose you expect to get it highlighted immediately after load because of this line: `$("#txt2").focus(function(){ $(this).addClass("focused")});`, but it only binds a handler to focus event. To run it and set a focus you must call this code: `                                                      $("#txt2").focus();` after event handler is added. Like in my latest demo

Comment: Ok that works now which prompts me to ask the question, do we really require so much code to just focus and highlite or can we reduce the code here?

Comment: Thanks FAngel for that explanation. Really helped me!

Comment: Say "thank you" to jQuery that you can write only "so" much code. You can make that line shorter making some named function which will set `focused` class. For instance, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/5/. If you have few fields, you may use class selector instead of id selector and do not duplicate that code for each element.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will focus the element. You can use the `:focus` pseudo selector in CSS to style the input as needed:

```
#txt1:focus {
    border: 1px solid #C00;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: As FAngel said, it does not work on IE7. Also how to remove focus when user moves to a different textbox

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work in IE7, FAngel's answer covers a workaround. As for removing the effect when focus is lost, the browser will take care of that for you due to the `:focus` selector.

Comment: It does, but the CSS for border was wrong, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/1/

Comment: My original requirement was when the page loads, I want to focus and highlight (border color or background color change) an input control. The demo does not focus the textbox on load.

Comment: Well you need to call `focus()` on the element then: http://jsfiddle.net/WEqZp/4/

Answer (score 0):

here you can use some css to apply border color, backgroung color. refer to below css which changes color when you focus on input

```
input:focus {
         font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border-color:#9ecaed;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ecaed;
}
```

put css attributes whichever you want to highlight after focusing it.